# React - Form submit fires onSubmit attached to parent of the form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, onsubmit

I am wondering if someone can explain this behavior to me. I have a React component made up of a Form (React Bootstrap) wrapped in a Modal (React Bootstrap). I accidentally attached the onSubmit to the surrounding Modal, and that function gets fired when the form is submitted. I did not expect the function to run, but expected the form action to happen (a Wufoo URL). Can someone tell me why the function runs? Is it a React thing? Native form behavior? A little of both?

Example (dumbed down and removed React Bootstrap):
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oq934any/19/)

```
const MyForm = () => {

  const submitForm = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    alert('submit');
  }

  return (
    <div onSubmit={submitForm}>
      <form>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: sounds like bubbling: https://dev.to/shimphillip/handing-javascript-events-efficiently-with-bubble-and-capture-4ha5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onSubmit` that's typically caught by the form's submit handler is just bubbling up through the DOM.

If you attach a `e.stopPropagation` to the `<form>` element, you'll see that `submitForm` is no longer called.

Answer (score 1):

in JS events can `bubble` from an inner element to an outer one. i attached a link in the comment below your question ;)